# How can the project A use libraries(i.e instructions) of project B, if both are in the same workspace?

Tags: c, eclipse, microcontroller, sd-card, cortex-m

Ok, to begin with, I am using eclipse and programming in C language. The device I am programming is STM32L476G. I was simulating one of the stm examples(audioRecorder DFSDM) and I wanted to write the results to SD card, mounted on the board. I have imported the FatFs SD card example, which uses RTOS, into the same workspace of the audioRecorder project. I have copied all the files from **includes** of the FatFs SD card project into the **includes**  of the audioRecorder project and tried to use some of the typical instructions(f_open etc.) but when I try to build, the compiler doesn't recognize these instructions, as if they are not a part of the project. I am not such a skilled user of eclipse, therefore I believe that I am doing something wrong in the procedure or I am missing some steps. Any advice is much appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yPLh.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: You should post the text of the error messages rather than a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

`main.c` must include the .h file(s) that define `f_open()`, `FA_READ`, and `FR_OK`.

Comment: Ok, the name of the .h file is ff.h. I put #include "ff.h" in the main.c of the DFSDM project, and I get this error:

 In file included from D://STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.8.0/Projects/STM32L476G_EVAL/Examples/DFSDM/DFSDM_AudioRecord/Src/main.c:40:0:
D:/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.8.0/Projects/STM32L476G_EVAL/Examples/DFSDM/DFSDM_AudioRecord/Inc/main.h:54:16: fatal error: ff.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. @kkrambo

Comment: @DaniloMaric That means the compiler cannot find ff.h.  The compiler searches for include files only in the folders (paths) that you specify.  Somewhere in the options for the project you can specify which paths the compiler should search for include files.  Add the path of ff.h to that list of include paths.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I found a way to include the necessary files. Now I get the error  `undefined reference to f_open`, which happens, I guess, because the f_open is defined in ff.c, but I don't know how to link ff.c to the main.c @kkrambo

Comment: @DaniloMaric, Yes, now you're getting a linker error.  You need to link with the library that contains the `f_open` routine.  Somewhere in the project settings there will be a place where you can specify a list of libraries to link with.  Add the library containing `f_open` to that list.